# Альтернатива циклам Java Android

Tags: java, android, сеть

Написал клиент на Java под Android. Метод Receive читает стрим в цикле и если данные прочитаны, обрабатывает их. Но использование цикла на Android не подходит т.к. будет быстрее садить батарею.
Например для проверки подключения к интернету я использую BroadcastReceiver и система присылает мне уведомления.

Есть ли возможность сделать тоже самое с сетевым буфером или как это правильно сделать?

Метод получения данных.

```
public void Receive() throws InterruptedException {
    while (socketClient.isConnected()) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[Config.BUFFER_SIZE];
        try {
            inputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            Packet packet = Packet.Deserialize(buffer);
            if(packet != null)
                event.onReceived(this, packet);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Не понятно в чём вы видите проблему - изложите подробнее. Быстрее садить батарею будет та задача, которая дольше и/или интенсивнее напрягает железо, а так же часто пробуждающая или постоянно не дающая войти в режим энергосбережения. Поясните как и для чего вы используете цикл. В общем смысле: прочитать поток данных с помощью цикла - это вполне нормальная и не расточительная практика. Удар по батарее будет, если цикл используется для ожидания какого-то события, которое неизвестно когда наступит, либо периодической проверки чего-либо.

Comment: Метод Receive читает стрим в цикле каждые 100 мс. Если метод не будет выполнен. То устройство не сможет перейти в режим энергосбережения и даже в спящем режиме выполнять работу.

Comment: А вариант использовать RxJava для того чтобы подписаться на сокет и использовать его как Observable вам не нравится? может неправильно понял вопрос, поправьте если не то пишу)

Comment: Вот этот вариант с событиями я и искал, просто я не знал как это можно реализовать и хотел подписаться на изменение стрима. Спасибо.